# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n^2 +2} - \sqrt{n^2 +1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that 
$$\lim_{n\to  \infty}(\sqrt{n^2+2} - \sqrt{n^2+1})=0.$$ 
But how can I prove this?

I only know that $(n^2+2)^{0.5} - \sqrt{n^2}$ is smaller than $\sqrt{n^2+2} - \sqrt{n^2}$ = $\sqrt{n^2+2} - n$.

Edit:
Thank Y'all for the nice and fast answers!

Comment: $$0\leq \sqrt{n^2+2}-\sqrt{n^2+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}\leq \frac{1}{2n}$$ should solve the mystery.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\displaystyle \sqrt{n^2+2}-\sqrt{n^2+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Try to multiply by $$1=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+2}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+2}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$
And use the face that
$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$( \sqrt{n^2+2}-\sqrt{n^2+1})(\sqrt{n^2+2}+\sqrt{n^2+1})=1$$

Thus

$$\sqrt{n^2+2}+\sqrt{n^2+1} \to \infty \implies \sqrt{n^2+2}-\sqrt{n^2+1}\to 0$$